# Cannot infer type parameter when using redux-rs with actions that are part of a fat enum

Tags: types, rust, compiler-errors

I'm using the `redux-rs` library to bring the redux pattern into Rust. I keep getting a weird type mismatch error since I'm trying to use actions that are part of a fat enum. With the following code:

```rust
fn root_reducer<T>(state: &State, action: &Action<T>) -> State
where
    T: Fn(State) -> State,
{
    match action {
        // Travel: Move the player forward by distance and move the date forward by days
        Action::Travel(days, distance) => State {
            date: state.date + *days,
            miles: state.miles - distance,
            ..*state
        },

        // Rest: Regenerate one health (up to 5) by stopping for rest_days
        Action::Rest(days) => State {
            date: state.date + *days,
            // No more than 5 health
            health: if state.health < 5 {
                state.health + 1
            } else {
                state.health
            },
            ..*state
        },

        // Hunt: Add one hundred pounds of food by stopping for hunt_days
        Action::Hunt => State {
            date: state.date + Duration::days(state.hunt_days),
            food: state.food + 100,
            ..*state
        },

        // Print the status of the game
        Action::Status(mut status_function) => status_function(*state),

        // Print commands and what they do
        Action::Help(mut help_function) => help_function(*state),

        // End the game
        Action::Quit(mut quit_mock) => quit_mock(*state),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let inital_state = State {
        date: Utc.ymd(2020, 3, 1),
        miles: 2000,
        food: 500,
        health: 5,
        hunt_days: 2,
    };
    let mut store = Store::new(root_reducer, inital_state);
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
type annotations needed for `redux_rs::store::Store<State, Action<T>>`
```

I tried adding a type annotation `<&dyn Fn(State) -> State>` to the `Store::new` call, but that just ended up creating the error:

```
cannot move out of `action.0` which is behind a shared reference
```

Comment: pick one or more https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+which+is+behind+a+shared+reference ?

Comment: @Stargateur I feel like I'm describing a specific issue here.